# How can I build a CSS selector that will highlight/outline a focused tab, while not effecting other non-tab widgets?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

## PROBLEM:

The user is able to utilize the "tab" key to navigate thru the page and land on the "tabs" panel.  However, when they initially land on the "tabs" panel - there is no visual indication (outline/highlight/etc) that they are there.

-As a result, they think their tab key (or the tab panel) is not working correctly.

## Notes:

My suspicion is that this new behavior is due to a CSS change that occurred when upgrading from 1.8.x to 1.10.x - But, of course, I'm not sure.

I've tried various css entries to cause the focused tab to visually outline/highlight...-So far, one that appears to have a visual effect on the tab is this selector:

```
    .ui-widget :focus     
    { 
        border-style: inset !important;
        border-width: 5px !important;
    }
```

...But, this selector is too broad and ***impacts other widgets*** on the page that are outside of the tabs() DIV.  --I only want to "highlight" focused tabs within the "tabs" DIV.

## Question:

How can I build a CSS selector that will highlight/outline a focused tab, ***while not effecting other non-tab widgets***?

(Thanks for your help)

## jquery script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#tabdiv').tabs();  //<== tabs
        $( "input[type=submit], a, button" ).button().click(function( event ) {event.preventDefault();});        
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
```

## css

```
    .ui-widget :focus 
    { 
        border-style: inset !important;
        border-width: 3px !important;
    }
```

## HTML snippet

```
    <div>
        <h1>body-A</h1>
        <div id="tabdiv">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabA">TabA</a></li>            
                <li><a href="#tabB">TabB</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabC">TabC</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabD">TabD</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabA">
                <div>
                    <span>tabA stuff</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabB">
                <div>
                    <span>tabB stuff</span>
                </div>
            </div>      
            <div id="tabC">
                <div>
                    <span>tabC stuff</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="tabD">
                <div>            
                    <span>tabD stuff</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>

            <button>A button element</button> 
            <input type="submit" value="A submit button" /> 
            <a href="#">An anchor</a>        
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML?

Comment: Doesn’t your tab widget have an id that you can use in the selector?

Comment: I don't see anything with a class of ui-widget???

Comment: .ui-widget is part of jquery-ui css

Comment: Ah, ok. So how about manually setting that class on something you expect so you can tell if it's a logic problem in setting the class or a CSS styling problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that to following works...

```
    .ui-widget#tabdiv :focus 
    { 
        border-style: inset !important;
        border-width: 3px !important;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following selector

```
[id~=tab]:focus
```

Comment: do you mean: [id~=tab]:focus{ border-style: inset !important; border-width: 3px !important; } ...? -that doesnt appear to work

Comment: I think he means `^=` and not `~=`